# Best Practices for Designing Domain Models with Calculated Properties in DDD & CQRS

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, clean-architecture

I'm currently developing a system following Domain-Driven Design (DDD) principles, and I've run into a design challenge that I believe others in the community might have faced.

In my domain model, I have entities with calculated properties. For instance, I have an entity class that contains a method IsActive, which determines the active state based on certain domain logic:

```
public bool IsActive() 
{
    return !_disabled && expiryDate > DateTime.UtcNow && _owner.IsActive;
}
```

The domain logic for this property can get complex, as it checks multiple fields and might invoke methods from associated entities or aggregates.

While this encapsulates the domain logic neatly within the entity, it poses a challenge when I attempt to use Command Query Responsibility Segregation (CQRS) for reads. Normally, with CQRS, I'd prefer loading a Data Transfer Object (DTO) directly from the database, which is more performant. However, because of the dynamic nature of this calculation, I find that I need to load the whole aggregate first and then perform the projection, filtering, and so forth.

This is especially concerning when considering the read side, where I might need to load many aggregates, which could have a significant performance impact.

Given this scenario:

How can I achieve a balance between properly encapsulating domain logic within my entities and ensuring efficient queries on the read side?
Are there any best practices or patterns to address this kind of situation?
Is there a recommended way to handle such calculated properties when designing domain models, especially when CQRS is in play?
I'd greatly appreciate insights and guidance from the community. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be clear about is that aggregates are a write-side concern (as what makes it an aggregate is that it *changes* as a unit).  If combining DDD with CQRS, there's no necessary relationship between the structure of the aggregate and what you expose in any read model.  Indeed, there's a school of thought which suggests that aggregates be designed strictly based on the commands they'll process which need to be mutually consistent (in the CAP sense more than the ACID sense of "C"): if some bit of state (whether field or computed property) in the aggregate doesn't affect how a command is processed, then it doesn't need to be in the aggregate at all.

One very useful general tactic is to denormalize for read models: if there's a query which will use `IsActive`, then make it a field.  The whole point of the read model is to optimize for queries: encapsulation doesn't really help you there.  You also have the freedom to tailor the model for particular queries (and if there are choices for one query that adversely impact another, you can have each query be handled by a different read model): you may be able to choose a model that lets you calculate properties in the course of executing the query.

I would generally urge some measure of caution, by the way, in having calculated properties in your aggregates that aren't pure (e.g. that depend on the current clock).  In lieu of the clock, I would strongly consider having a scheduler (perhaps fed by a simple read model that is just tracking expiry dates) arrange to process a command that moves the aggregate to expired at the appropriate time.